# How to download file from docker container?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm using this Docker Container https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity .
I've made few changes and would like to backup files from it to my hard drive. I can't find solution to do so.

Comment: You have done few changes to what? please be more specific.

Answer (score 30):

Syntax to copy files/folders from Docker container to local filesystem is

```
docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH
```

**Ex :** `docker cp  b8ddea5d8fad:/mnt/mydir/ ./localDir`

Syntax to copy files/folders from local filesystem to docker container is

```
docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH CONTAINER:DEST_PATH
```

**Ex :** `docker cp ./localDir/dirToCopy b8ddea5d8fad:/mnt/newDir/`

Docker Documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use 'docker cp' command to retrieve particular files.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/